# Execute commands from an external text file in Stata

Tags: stata

I have a text file that contains Stata variable labeling commands that I would like to execute. Here are the first few lines:

```
"label var q0p5a "Location""
"label var q1p0 "Knowledge/involvement about the project""
label var q1p1 "Received Counseling"
label var q2p0 "Workload as a result of the project"
```

In an attempt to open and run the commands I do as follows:

```
file open labelscommands using D:\Datasets\varlabels.txt, read 
file read labelscommands line
di `line'
```

Gives the error:

```
label var q0p5a Location"" invalid name
```

And running  again:

```
file read labelscommands line
`line'
```

Gives the error:

```
unrecognized command:  "label var q1p0  invalid command name
```

And once more (note the line 3 in the txt does not have quotes, testing if the issue is due to the quotes):

```
file read labelscommands line
`line'
variable q1p1 not found
```

How can I execute the commands from the text file?

Comment: The double quotes `" "` around entire commands are utterly wrong, so remove them.

Comment: @nick Yes, removing the quotes contributed to the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You type:

```
do D:\Datasets\varlabels.txt
```

Comment: The `file` command is much more advanced than the `do` command. Systematic reading of the Stata Users' Manual [U[ might reveal many others you would find useful.